# ML.Net n-gram word similarity

Tags: python, c#, tensorflow, n-gram, ml.net

Please tell me how you can implement the task of determining the similarity of words using n-grams on ML.Net?

Example: there is the word "adidas". The user enters the word "adibas". I need to train the neural network in such a way that it understands that the user wanted to enter the word "adidas". How can this be implemented on ML.Net or Tensorflow?

Here is an example that I implemented, but errors occur.

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.Data;
using Microsoft.ML.Trainers;
using Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Text;

namespace NGram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mlContext = new MLContext();

            var samples = new List<TextData>()
            {
                new TextData() {Text = "adidas"},
            };

            var dataview = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(samples);

            var textPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Text.TokenizeIntoCharactersAsKeys(
                    "Tokens",
                    "Text"
                )

                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Tokens"))
                .AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext)
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.ProduceNgrams("NgramFeatures",
                    "Tokens",
                    ngramLength: 2,
                    useAllLengths: false,
                    weighting: NgramExtractingEstimator.WeightingCriteria.Tf)
                )
                .Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.Sdca(labelColumnName: null, featureColumnName: "NgramFeatures"));


            // Fit to data.
            var textTransformer = textPipeline.Fit(dataview);
            var transformedDataView = textTransformer.Transform(dataview);

            var predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<TextData,
                TransformedTextData>(textTransformer);

            var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(new TextData {Text = "fadida"});

            Console.WriteLine("Number of Features: " + prediction.NgramFeatures.Length);

            VBuffer<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> slotNames = default;
            transformedDataView.Schema["NgramFeatures"].GetSlotNames(ref slotNames);

            var NgramFeaturesColumn = transformedDataView.GetColumn<VBuffer<
                float>>(transformedDataView.Schema["NgramFeatures"]);
            var slots = slotNames.GetValues();
            Console.Write("N-grams: ");
            foreach (var featureRow in NgramFeaturesColumn)
            {
                foreach (var item in featureRow.Items())
                    Console.Write($"{slots[item.Key]}  ");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // Print the first 10 feature values.
            Console.Write("Features: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < prediction.NgramFeatures.Length; i++)
                Console.Write($"{prediction.NgramFeatures[i]:F4}  ");

            //  Expected output:
            //   Number of Features: 52
            //   N-grams:   This|is|an  is|an|example  an|example|to  example|to|compute  to|compute|n-grams.  N-gram|is|a  is|a|sequence  a|sequence|of  sequence|of|'N'  of|'N'|consecutive  ...
            //   Features:     1.0000      1.0000          1.0000           1.0000             1.0000            0.0000      0.0000          0.0000          0.0000          0.0000          ...

            // var trainer = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.SdcaLogisticRegression(labelColumnName: "Label",
            //     featureColumnName: "NgramFeatures");
        }

        private class TextData
        {
            [LoadColumn(0)] 
            public bool Label { get; set; }

            [LoadColumn(1)]
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        private class TransformedTextData : TextData
        {
            public float[] NgramFeatures { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.